# Zeroclipboard: Copy to clipboard the data returned by the server

Tags: angularjs, zeroclipboard

I am using ZeroClipboard with AngularJs. My workflow is the following:

1. initialise the ZeroClipboard client for the buttons with the class "grab-button"
2. when one of these buttons is clicked, a request is made to the server.
3. the response from the server has to be stored to the clipboard.

Is it possible to do it with ZeroClipboard? I couldn't make it work as the http request to the server returns a promise and copy to clipboard is performed before I have my response.